# Beginning with D3.js and parallel coordinates

Tags: html, d3.js, parallel-coordinates

I would like to use the parallel coordinate toolkit from [syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/#](https://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/#).

As I am new to the D3.js framework, I am encountering some trouble to begin and visualize data locally.
What I am trying to achieve is to use one of the standalone HTML examples (e.g. [brushing.html](https://syntagmatic.github.io/parallel-coordinates/examples/brushing.html)) and edit the data table with my own data.

I stored locally (in a Windows folder):

- the brushing.html example file
- the cars.csv file
- the D3.js library files from d3js.org (d3.min.js and d3.js)

When I load the HTML file in my browser, only the text displays, not the parallel coordinates themselves.

What am I missing/doing wrong? Should I be able to display locally the same result as what appears in brushing.html?
I checked out several tutorials for D3.js, but they generaly skip these preliminary requirements step. Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: Open a console in your browser and check error message.

Comment: Thanks, I did so and that helped solved the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the straightforward comment to my question, I was able to identify the issues checking the browser's console.

It mainly came down to redefining paths to the different files, and eventually downloading the missing packages from the [corresponding Github page](https://github.com/syntagmatic/parallel-coordinates) https://github.com/syntagmatic/parallel-coordinates

I can now test the tool locally with custom data.